# xtable with various column types

Tags: r, xtable

I am trying to use xtable on my table with various column types including numbers, latex commands and string.

Example:

```
a1 <- paste("\\multirow{2}{*}{", c(1, 2, 3, 4),"}", sep = "")
a2 <- rep(NA, 4)

riffle <- function (a,b) { 
n <- min(length(a), length(b)) 
p1 <- as.vector(rbind(a[1:n], b[1:n])) 
p2 <- c(a[-(1:n)], b[-(1:n)]) 
c(p1, p2) 
}

 a <- riffle(a1, a2)
 b <- rnorm(8, 0, 1)
 c <- rep(c("a", "b"), 2)
 d <- rexp(8, 2)*10
 tab <- cbind(a, b, c, d)
 print(xtable(tab), include.rownames = FALSE)
```

However, output is not satisfactory:

```
 \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
      \hline
    a & b & c & d \\ 
      \hline
       $\backslash$multirow\{2\}\{*\}\{1\} & 0.567183110307595 & a & 17.4277735359976 \\ 
       & -1.45110043335658 & b & 5.78849371967322 \\ 
      $\backslash$multirow\{2\}\{*\}\{2\} & 1.19040399046713 & a & 0.692481031836454 \\ 
       & 1.08180700975955 & b & 8.30343133216384 \\ 
      $\backslash$multirow\{2\}\{*\}\{3\} & 0.770520985309568 & a & 4.95384422575539 \\ 
       & 0.318790423633696 & b & 1.55130311148241 \\ 
      $\backslash$multirow\{2\}\{*\}\{4\} & 0.672622845121449 & a & 6.01311508645727 \\ 
       & 1.09581061308637 & b & 2.99998417729512 \\ 
       \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \hline
a & b & c & d \\ 
  \hline
   \multirow{2}{*}{1} & 0.567  & a & 17 \\ 
                      & -1.451 & b & 6 \\ 
  \multirow{2}{*}{2}  & 1.190  & a & 1 \\ 
                      & 1.082  & b & 8 \\ 
  \multirow{2}{*}{3}  & 0.771  & a & 5 \\ 
                      & 0.319  & b & 2 \\ 
  \multirow{2}{*}{4}  & 0.673  & a & 6 \\ 
                      & 1.096  & b & 3 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Including the different rounding of numeric columns (which is normally feasible with `digits` command when printing, but doesn't work for my table)

Comment: For the rounding issue, try creating `tab` using `data.frame` rather than `cbind` (i.e., `tab <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)`. `cbind` creates a matrix, which means every value must be of the same mode. Thus, your numbers are coerced to character and rounding doesn't work. If you start with a data frame, different columns can have different modes, so your numeric columns will stay numeric and the `digits` argument to `xtable` will work.

Comment: If you want different numbers of digits in different columns, before running `xtable`, round each column to the number of digits you want and convert to character so that `xtable` won't pad with trailing zeros.

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you for your reply! Good point, however, even when working with data.frame I get the same output as above. So there has to be another problem.

Comment: What if you do, for example: `tab <- data.frame(a, b, c, d);
tab$b = as.character(sprintf("%1.3f", tab$b));
tab$d = as.character(sprintf("%1.0f", tab$d)); print(xtable(tab), include.rownames = FALSE)`

Comment: Or this: `tab <- data.frame(a, b, c, d); print(xtable(tab, digits=3), include.rownames = FALSE)`.

Comment: @eipi10 Well, the first one works quite fine, but it won't be really pleasant when considering more columns and/or different number of rounding digits. The solution for rounding is to use `digits= c(0, 0, 3, 0, 0)`. However this does not solve the problem about latex comand. Still get `$\backslash$multirow\{2\}\{*\}\{1\}` instead of `\multirow{2}{*}{1}`

Comment: So, there is code which solves my problem `sanitize.text.function = force`, this one print `\multirow{2}{*}{1}` correctly. @eipi10 Thanks for your help

Comment: @Adela People who stumble across the same problem will appreciate if you post your solution as an answer. Also note that from your comment it is not obvious that this option `sanitize.text.function = force` is supplied to the `print` function that also takes in `xtable(...)`, not directly to the `xtable` function. If you write an answer, you can elaborate all this and thereby help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `sanitize.text.function = force` within `print()` function for `xtable` object.

```
tab <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
print(xtable(tab), include.rownames = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = force)
```

Output:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrlr}
  \hline
  a & b & c & d \\ 
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{1} &  1.26 & a & 2.43 \\ 
   & -0.42 & b & 3.60 \\ 
  \multirow{2}{*}{2} & -0.14 & a & 6.27 \\ 
   & -0.12 & b & 1.68 \\ 
  \multirow{2}{*}{3} &  0.70 & a & 2.15 \\ 
   & -1.05 & b & 0.62 \\ 
  \multirow{2}{*}{4} &  2.29 & a & 0.84 \\ 
   & -0.21 & b & 3.36 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```